# call different applications views to a main application view in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

i have three different applications and a main application ,where i need to display the all three application views in my main application view.

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'
    url(r'^app1/', include('app1.urls')),
    url(r'^app2/', include('app2.urls')),
    url(r'^app3/', include('app3.urls'))

]
```

however there are some views from different applications which need to be displayed in main application url calling.

In main application view :

```
def index(request):
     return render_to_response(main template+all three applications templates)
```

Comment: Views and templates don't "belong" to an app, you're free to use them anywhere. However, you can't use multiple templates to generate a single response, you'll need to use extends and includes in the main template to achieve that.

Comment: You need to build out one template, and then include the necessary pieces in them.

Comment: @knbk slight clarification: it's perfectly possible to use multiple templates in a response (just render them separately and concatenate them); what's not possible is to use multiple views.